# Register custom NHibernate Interceptor via Windsor

Tags: nhibernate, castle-windsor, iinterceptor

I created a simple AuditInterceptor: EmptyInterceptor now I wonder how can I register this new interceptor with my application using Windsor?

Answer (score 2):

Use the NHibernate facility, then register a `Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.IConfigurationContributor` implementation that adds your interceptor to the `NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration` instance (by calling `SetInterceptor()`)

Comment: thanks @mausch do you know is it possible to register using windsor.boo?